# How should I convey my Best wishes

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

My aunt is going to USA as her husband got a job there. So I want to convey my best wishes to her. But I am confused in sentence formation. So what should I say to her?

Comment: This site isn't a brainstorming service!

Answer (score 1):

All the best (or Good luck) for your new life in the USA! And, 'Bon Voyage!'

Please note, "the USA", always.